# ionic 3 error itms - 90725 IOS

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS '10.3' SDK. All new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS '11.0' SDK or later, included in Xcode [9.0] or later. Please update Xcode and rebuild your app." 
im using El capitain os , can i update xcode to 9.0 ? (im using xcode 7)

Comment: Did you try to update? You have no real choice...

Comment: i can't update it on vmware.